# Outlook Mail addin reading body content error

Tags: outlook, office365, office365api

I'm trying to develop an [Outlook mail addin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161135.aspx) to access the body content of an email.

This is how I'm writing the JavaScript code to according to the [Documentation provided by MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt269089.aspx).

```
        Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync("html", function(result){

            $("#mytext3").val(result);

        });
```

When I debug this with chrome, This is the error message I found.

```
Uncaught Sys.ArgumentException: Sys.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

Parameter name: options

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call should work (I just tried it), but the `result` passed to your callback is an object, with the body in `result.value`.

You could try passing an `options` parameter, something like:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(
  "html", 
  { asyncContext: "This is passed to the callback" },
  function(result){
    $("#mytext3").val(result.value);
  }
);
```

Comment: I tried doing it. But i still get this error message. `Uncaught Sys.ParameterCountException: Sys.ParameterCountException: The given parameters do not match the expected format.` I can understand the issue is in the format of options parameter. But i couldn't find it's format. Not providing the options object is now allowed as well.

Comment: The format of `options` is just a single value, `asyncContext`, as shown in my example. There's no other option for `body.getAsync`. What version of Office.js are you using, and what version of Outlook/Outlook Web Access is this happening in?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Office APIs. The office.js file i could find contains `Office JavaScript API library Version: 16.0.6207.1000 ' In the start. I used Visual Studio and NapaCloudApp to try my code in outlook.

Comment: Hmm. Try an experiment: try this code: 
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(
  { coercionType: "html" },
  function(result){
    $("#mytext3").val(result.value);
  }
);

Comment: Ok. You probably have an older version of Office.js. You should update your HTML pages to use the Office.js on our CDN: https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js

Comment: We are finding that recently we have been getting different versions of outlook-web-16.00.js, one of which, "Version: 16.0.6018.1000" per the comment at the top of the file, works as documented with a string coercionType, the other, "Version: 16.0.4017.3000 Build Time: 07/15/2015", works with the coercionType in the options argument as @JasonJohnston suggests. The fun part is it doesn't seem to be based so much about whether we ask for /1/ or /1.1/, but about which specific server serves up the request.

Comment: Yes. It turns out this was a bug that is being patched across servers now. It should be as I posted in my answer.